# Firebase database web quickstart error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just tried to run the Firebase quickstart for Web from - https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js

Setup works (it works for storage) but i cant add a post on the Firebase sample. Getting this error

> main.js:309 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null
>       at http://localhost:5000/scripts/main.js:309:38(anonymous function) @ main.js:309

the entire code for submitting a post

```
 messageForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (messageInput.value && titleInput.value) {
      var postText = messageInput.value;
      messageInput.value = '';
      // [START single_value_read]
      var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var username = snapshot.val().username;
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        writeNewPost(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
            titleInput.value, postText).then(function() {
              myPostsMenuButton.click();
            });
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      });
      // [END single_value_read]
    }
  };
```

looks like the snapshot is not empty, but i can get the username to return

thanks,

Comment: The snapshot.val(); return null...

Comment: can you show us the database tree?

Comment: The quickstart is meant to be used in combination with the documentation, which provides context for the code snippets. If you're having a hard time getting things to work, I recommend studying the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: @adolfosrs DB is empty... i would expect the app to init it.

Comment: if your database is empty you wont be able to retrieve the '/users/userId/username' since this data dont exists. If you are already authenticating your users you can create the user/userId node whenever a new user is authencitated and then you will be able to retrieve it.